# Merging two foreach in php laravel/api

Tags: php, laravel, api

Good day! i had success in finding answers that shortens my code. Someone said that i can merge the foreach statements for it to become even shorter. but i searched everywhere but cant seem to find any solution with similar codes that i have. I just want to know how can i merge the two foreach.

here is my code:

```
    $newArray = [];
    $keys = ['name', 'sex', 'age', 'height', 'weight'];
    foreach(explode(PHP_EOL, Storage::get('upload/test.txt')) as $key => $line) {
        $finalArray = [];
        foreach( explode(',', $line) as $i => $value){
            $finalArray[ $keys [ $i ] ] = $value;       
        }
        array_push($newArray, $finalArray); 
    }
    die(json_encode($newArray));
```

here is another code with the same output as the first code:

```
        $newArray = array();
        foreach(explode(PHP_EOL, Storage::get('upload/test.txt')) as $key => $line) {
            array_push($newArray, explode(',', $line)); 
        }
        $finalArray = array();
        foreach($newArray as $key) {
                $key = [
                            "name" => $key[0],
                            "sex" => $key[1],
                            "age" => $key[2],
                            "height" => $key[3],
                            "weight" => $key[4],
                        ];
                        array_push($finalArray, $key); 
        }
        die(json_encode($finalArray));
```

Comment: By using single for loop, not foreach loop

Comment: check this!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53496854/laravel-php-combine-two-foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make it simpler by using [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
$newArray = [];
$keys = ['name', 'sex', 'age', 'height', 'weight'];
foreach (explode(PHP_EOL, Storage::get('upload/test.txt')) as $line) {
    $newArray[] = array_combine($keys, explode(',', $line));
}
```

Or you could use [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and do something like:

```
$keys = ['name', 'sex', 'age', 'height', 'weight'];

$newArray = array_map(function ($line) use ($keys) {
    return array_combine($keys, explode(',', $line));
}, explode(PHP_EOL, Storage::get('upload/test.txt')));
```